# Where does the $2$ in Ricci flow come from?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convention, ricci-flow

I started learning about Ricci flow recently, which is always given as
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=-2\textrm{Ric}.
$$
It would seem more natural to me to define Ricci flow instead by the equation
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=-\textrm{Ric},
$$
which omits the $2$. The only real difference in behavior between this flow and Ricci flow is that this one flows at half the rate. Wikipedia claims that the choice of $2$ in the equation is an arbitrary convention, but this is hard for me to stomach, since conventions in math are almost always motivated by something. Is there a good reason that Ricci flow is defined the way it is, or is the convention really arbitrary?

Comment: Because we prefer that the equation for the metric to look like $$\partial_tg = \Delta g + \ldots $$

Comment: So I guess it's the same question as whether "the heat equation" is $\partial_t u = \Delta u$ or $\partial_t u = \frac{1}{2} \Delta u$.  Which maybe is the same question as "are you an analyst or a probabilist?".